# AngularJS - count json with "x" value

Tags: json, angularjs, count

I want to make a count on status, Where status value is = 10.
And display it.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController">



    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in Number">
            <td>{{ x.number }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.resource }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.status }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
<script>
function customersController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("mylocalhostlink")
    .success(function (response) { $scope.Number = response });

}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Sry i formulated that question pretty bad. i have 3 diffrent status, with 10-20 and 30. I wanna make a counter on how many i have on 10, 20, and 30, so it will be like Status: 30 = 100 times, Status: 20 = 50 times Status: 10 = 33 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will probably want to use angulars foreach within your success part. Docs on foreach here -[link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) I've created this fiddle that shows what I mean - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7a9wdv8q/22/)

Code from the jsfiddle below:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="customersController">
<h1> Test </h1>
<h4> Tens = {{tens}}</h4> 
<h4> Twenties = {{twenties}}</h4> 
<h4> Thirties = {{thirties}}</h4> 
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in Number">
        <td>{{ x.number }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.resource }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.status }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('customersController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Number = [
        {number: 1, resource: 1, status: 10},
        {number: 1, resource: 1, status: 10},
        {number: 2, resource: 2, status: 20},
        {number: 3, resource: 3, status: 30}
    ];

    // Set your variables to 0 at first
    $scope.tens = 0;
    $scope.twenties = 0;
    $scope.thirties = 0;

    // Use angulars for each to loop over your numbers
    angular.forEach($scope.Number, function(value, key) {
        // Increment each number by one when you hit it
        if (value.status == 10){
            $scope.tens++
        }else if (value.status == 20){
            $scope.twenties++
        }else if (value.status == 30){
            $scope.thirties++
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sry i formulated that question pretty bad. i have 3 diffrent status, with 10-20 and 30. I wanna make a counter on how many i have on 10, 20, and 30, so it will be like


Status: 30 = 100 times,
Status: 20 = 50 times
Status: 10 = 33 times

Comment: you will probably want to use angulars foreach within your success part. Docs on foreach here - [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

I've created this fiddle that shows what I mean - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7a9wdv8q/22/)

Comment: No worries. I've updated my answer so it fits the actual question now :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<div ng-controller="customersController" ng-init="memo={}">
    <div ng-repeat="x in Number" ng-init="memo[x.status] = memo[x.status] + 1"></div>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="(k, v) in memo">
            <td>{{ k }}</td>
            <td>{{ v }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```